# iOS app does not show a pending edit (upon both saving the edit and subsequent edits)

Tags: bug, edits, ios-app

> This issue is in fact in two parts, showing up in two distinct parts of the UI, although the root cause may be the same. Should I post two separate bug
> reports?
>
> 1. Once an edit has been made and saved, any subsequent view of the post
>    does not show the pending edited version of the post
> 2. During a subsequent edit, the previous, now pending, edit is not reflected
>    in the text being edited

#### Part One

Taking the first part of the bug, when using a browser, on a standard Mac/PC/*nix desktop, and an edit has been made and saved to a post, when the same user, who made the edit, looks a the post, while the edit is still pending, is presented both with a banner stating "Thanks for your edit" etc., but more importantly, IMHO, the post reflects the pending edit, like so:

Before Edit

[image: Pre Edit]

After Edit

[image: Post Edit]

I am sure that most of us are familiar with this.  However, if an edit is made using the iOS app, then the "After Edit" scenario is not shown, and instead the post when viewed looks as if it has not been edited, with no pending edit, and the proposed edits are not shown to the user who made those edits, using the same device on which those edits were made. In addition, the "Thanks for your edit..." banner/notification is not displayed.

#### Part Two

Examining the second part of the bug, consider the following, when using a browser, on a standard Mac/PC/*nix desktop:

A third party contributor edits a question (or answer), that was posted by someone else, and submits that edit. Now *before* that edit is approved, if a *further* edit is made (by the same third party contributor) then the *previous* (now pending) edit is shown, if one is using a browser. Additional edits can then be made, and those edits get 'lumped together' for approval. In fact one can make as many edits as one wants, prior to approval and they all get aggregated. Upon each subsequent edit, the contributor can see all of the previous pending edits up to that point.

I'm sure that anyone who has ever edited someone else's post is aware of this, and that it is by design, and a necessary feature - otherwise editing would quickly become a chore.

However, if one uses the iOS app, edits a post, submits that edit and then, shortly after, attempts to add an additional edit (to the same post), when the edit button is clicked (for a second time), the post in its *original unedited form* is presented to the user. What should show up is the previous (awaiting approval) edit, as happens when using a browser.

So, basically, a user can only make one edit, and then needs to wait for approval. If an additional edit is required, the user has to re-type in the previous edit and then make further changes.

---

It is just a question of usability - I constantly find myself making an edit using the iOS app, and *then* have to re-edit the post in a browser to make additional changes. It is 100% reproducible.  I am posting this as a bug, although if it is *by design* then the tag will be to be changed to 'feature-request'.

I hope that this is clear. I can provide screen shots if necessary, however, the screenshots will not show any issue, just the post in its unedited form and so are somewhat pointless.

I can not find a question like this being asked already, so hopefully not a duplicate.

Comment: Any updates...?

Comment: @54D - not heard even a whisper...